# Python getting running Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm doing a project with Python and in my code I had to start some threads. Now I need to call a thread to stop it from, but from another class. Is there some way to get a list of all running threads?

Comment: please add some code or external source what u have tried so far??

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use threading.enumerate() : Python documentation about it [here](https://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate)

```py
for thread in threading.enumerate(): 
    print(thread.name)
```

Comment: threading.enumerate() doesn't work for all instance types. I have a basic_scaling application, but when I start 10 background threads and have them all busy (they're started, not blocked, not sleeping, not done, and verifiably modifying data,) threading.enumerate() returns [<_MainThread(MainThread, started -25756864)>]

Comment: threading.enumrate() returns all thread 'objects' that is why you got [<_MainThread(MainThread, started -25756864)>] as the output. Try this :

for thread in threading.enumerate():
    print(thread.name)

Answer (score 8):

[threading.enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate) can be used for getting the list of running threads (Thread objects). As per library reference, running threads imply

1. All Thread objects that are currently alive, created using threading module
2. Daemonic threads (whose presence doesn't prevent the process from exiting)
3. Dummy thread objects created by current thread (Threads directly created from C code. They are always alive and daemonic and cannot be joined)
4. Main Thread (Default thread in python)

It excludes Threads that are not yet started and already terminated.

You can use [threading.active_count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.active_count) to get the length of the list returned by threading.enumerate