# How to kill C pthreads created by python ctypes.LoadLibrary

Tags: python, c, multithreading

The module I'm using loads C library via `ctypes.LoadLibrary` in `__init__` and calls a function which creates two processes using `pthread_create` C api. Thread IDs are not stored anywhere. These processes contain `while(1)` loops that read and write to serial port. I want to be able to kill the library threads, use said serial port for other purposes and then restore the module functionality with `importlib.reload`. Right now serial port remains inaccessible until I kill python top-most script with ctrl+c.

Comment: Have you got other threads running in your process?

Comment: Do you mean python threads? Yes, the python module is used by python class derived from threading.Thread.

Comment: To be clear, you're not trying to kill child processes, you need to kill two threads with unknown Id's, out of an unspecified number of other threads, all or some of which may be indistinguishable from the two you want to kill?

Comment: You may be able to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37942018/3150445) to enumerate and record the existing threads prior to invoking the library init, then enumerate again, to find the two newly added threads, but that's dependent on other threads not also spawning new threads in the background.

Comment: I don't know how are python threads different from the ones created using pthread in C library and hope there's some mechanism in ctypes to list all threads created with it.

Comment: Threads are an OS feature. My Python is very rusty, but I think all it does is give you a portable interface to the underlying OS thread API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot kill a thread without its cooperation. It absolutely will not work. You have two choices:

1. Change the code of the library or module so that it supports clean shutdown and the threads terminate themselves. This will require changing the `while(1)` loops so they have some way to exit.
2. Isolate the library or module into its own process. You can safely reach in from the outside to terminate a process or write code to terminate the process from the inside without changing the library or module.

Fixing code that doesn't support clean shutdown so that it does support clean shutdown is the better option if it's practical. But sometimes it can be very difficult to add support for clean shutdown to complex code that doesn't have it. In an ideal world, every programmer would design support for clean shutdown into every library or module.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are not saving a reference to the thread. You can't kill it specifically. The easiest and most reliable way is to save the thread ID somewhere.

Some comments talk about listing threads to kill them. Don't do that! You can't tell which thread are your own and killing someone else thread is not nice. Just save the ID, it's simple and robust.

Comment: The OP already specified that saving the Id's is not possible, they are created by a third party library. Discovering those Id's after they are created, will not be a problem, if other threads aren't spawning additional threads.

Comment: Relying on having no other threads being spawned is extremely fragile. The glibc itself spawn threads with AIO and maybe just the Python interpreter does also. The best solution is to fix the C code design flaw or to use another module. It seem rude as solution, but it's simpler and more robust to fix the source of the problem than doing guess play.