# How to make all python threads that are created from the main thread are daemon threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

I use a lot of libraries that create their own threads. I want to all threads stop when the main tread is down. Basically, I want that all threads should be a daemon thread. Potentially, I could rewrite all libraries and make them create daemon threads, but it will take a huge amount of time.

So my question is, Is there is a way how to make all threads are daemon threads?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to set the deamon flag on threads that are not created by your own code?

Comment: @timgeb Yup, you right!

Comment: A bit clumsy but you could have a thread that periodically [finds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37940460/python-getting-running-threads) all running threads and sets the deamon flag.

Comment: @timgeb No. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon "This must be set before start() is called, otherwise RuntimeError is raised."

Comment: @h4z3 bummer, thanks for the info

Comment: Docs say that being a daemon is inherited. Main thread is not a daemon... but maybe you can wrap your code starting that other stuff in a daemon thread? Or even wrap whole code and just manually wait for that one thread (because it's a daemon for inheritance purposed but we want to treat it like non-daemon)?

Comment: Someone wrote and deleted their message about trying to reassign treading.Thread. Idk why they deleted (confusion as to how importing would work) but it may be a good idea (when we do `import threading` and not `from threading import Thread`, reassigning threading.Thread should work because we can only have one version of the module in memory).

Comment: But: to be lazy and not bother with proper rewriting I'd say have a copy of `treading.py` with changed default in your main directory because cwd is always added to PATH. :P

Comment: Thanks for advices guys! Found a solution. `class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #kwargs['daemon'] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
threading.Thread = CustomThread`

Comment: You can write it as answer, for those who will seek similar thing. But you obviously won't get points for marking it as solution :P

Comment: @h4z3 Yeah also saw that comment, and it seems to be working as expected! Little bit hacky maybe :)

Comment: @IgorAlex your solution is not restricted to threads spawned from the main thread (as the question title suggests), though

Comment: @timgeb Why? If you insert that code in the entrypoint of your python program. Then all threads will daemon. Or I'm something missing here?

Comment: Yes, exactly, *all* threads. As I understand your question title, you want to restrict the enforced daemon flag to threads spawned from the main thread. Not all threads spawned from anywhere.

Comment: @timgeb Yeah... there is might be a problem if we want to make daemon threads only from the main thread. But it's working for me now, as expected because of all threads that i started from the main.